# Need help proving the power series of a function.

Tags: complex-analysis

We want to show that
$$\log(1-z)=-\sum_{k=1}\dfrac{z^k}{k},\quad z\in D=\{z: |z|<1\}$$
I honestly have no idea where to start so if someone would please help guide me through the problem that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Start with

$$   \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x} ,$$

then integrate both sides from 0 to $x$.

Comment: Since the question is about a complex Taylor series, this might be a slightly complicated approach; one could, of course, make an argument about accumulation points and whatnot to conclude equality in the entire disk.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(z) = log(1 - z) + \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{z^k}{k}$. Taking derivative:

$f'(z) = -\dfrac{1}{1 - z} + \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{k-1} = 0$ on $D$. So $f$ is constant, and $f(z) = f(0) = 0$. Done.